# How to fix InvalidImageFormat in Microsoft Azure's Computer Vision using image from google storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, google-cloud-platform

I'm setting up Microsoft Azure's Computer Vision with Image URL from my google cloud storage, but whenever I upload photo from my google cloud storage the response was 'InvalidImageFormat', but when I use image url other than google cloud storage, it works

I've tried changing the URL and checking if the picture that I've uploaded have size more than the maximum limit size, but it's less than the maximum limit size

```
const cognitiveServices = require('cognitive-services');
const fs = require('fs')

const parameters = {
    'visualFeatures': 'Description',
    'language': 'en'
};

const body = {"url" :'<from google storage>'}
const headers = { "content-type": "application/json" };

const checkImage = new cognitiveServices.computerVision({
    apiKey: "<api key>",
    endpoint: "<end point>"
})

checkImage.analyzeImage({
    parameters,
    body,
    headers
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

I expect the output to give the 200 response not giving 400 status code with 'InvalidImageFormat'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even you set the content with public access in google storage, the URL you get is not the direct URL for your file.

You can make a GET request with the URL first, and you will get a response with 307 status code, and you will get the redirect URL from the response header:

[image]

With the new URL, you can get the image, and use it in your js code:

[image]

The result:

[image]

---

Suggestions:

You can use Azure storage. With public access, you can directly use the URL of your blob. Here is a storage blob file for your test: `https://storagetest789.blob.core.windows.net/pub/p033tw9j.jpg`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it's now solved.